# SCD type2 example implementation in sql developer

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle12c, scd

I am trying to implement a example of SCD type2. so i am creating a table with empid,ename,location,hiredate,startdate,enddate and a flag. now initally suppose hiredate and startdate be 01-jan-2012 and enddate by default is 01-jan-2099. and for wherever the enddate is 01-jan-2099,the flag remains "Y", shwing current ,active information.

now whenever someone updates the location, a new row is added of that employee with the new.startdate to the updated old end date of the previous row of the same employee(old row) and new.enddate becomes by default to 01-jan-2099, and set flags to "Y".

the old row of the employee is now represents historic data, setting the enddate to systemdate and flag to "N". I am stuck ,unable to understand the order in which actions of triggers to perform.

Comment: @GurV any idea about this one?

Comment: I am generally against "fake" dates, either future or past, as they can have a big negative effect on the optimizer.